# Listar tabelas com coluna específica

Tags: android, sqlite

Estou criando uma aplicação em Android usando SQLite e preciso de obter uma lista de tabelas com uma coluna especifica como por exemplo:

```
SELECT table_name FROM sqlite_master WHERE table_column_map = 'imagem'
```

É possivel fazer isso?

Comment: É possível conseguir o que você quer mas não desta forma já que o SQLite não gurada os dados da tabela em uma forma fácil de fazer *query*. Não vou tentar responder porque essencialmente deve ser feito com código Java no Android e não conheço a API para tentar montar um código.

Answer (score 1):

Acabei por construir esta função para solucionar o meu problema:

```
public ArrayList<Object> getTablesWhereColumns(String[] columns) {
    ArrayList<Object> tables = getTables();
    ArrayList<Object> requestedTables = new ArrayList<Object>();

    for (Object table : tables){
        Cursor cursor = mDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM "+table.toString()+" LIMIT 1", null);
        String[] columnNames = cursor.getColumnNames();

        for (String columnName : columnNames) {
            if (Arrays.asList(columns).contains(columnName)) {
                requestedTables.add(table.toString());
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    return requestedTables;
}
```

Utilização:

```
ArrayList<Object> tables = crud.getTablesWhereColumns(new String[]{"image", "video", "video_image"});
```